# Python: This should be impossible, shouldn't it?

Tags: python, django

This is part of my Django application which is saving a user's profile in a special way.

```
class SomeUser:

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.logged_in = True
        self.profile = request.user.get_profile()
        self.favorites = self.profile.favorites.all().values_list('pk', flat=True)

    def save(self, resp):
        print "1: " + str(self.favorites)
        self.profile.favorites = self.favorites
        print "2: " + str(self.favorites)
        self.profile.save()
        return resp
```

Output:

```
1: [68, 56]
2: []
```

How is this even possible? I'm not fiddling with `self.favorites` at all! How can its value change?

EDIT: Updated the question with more info.

Comment: With just that it's pretty tricky to say. It's possible for that to happen, for example 'hello' could be a property, which writes to 'favorites'

Comment: If you don't assign self.hello to self.favorites does this still happen?

Comment: @Pynt: No, only if the assignment is in place.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem. Perhaps, you should provide more detail.

Comment: We can't help unless you provide enough information to reproduce the issue. Suffice to say that there are numerous ways this is possible, and without knowing the context it's fruitless to ask us to guess between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing self.favorites is some kind of iterator, maybe a django QuerySet.

The first str() runs the iterator and empties it out

The second str() runs the iterator again and it is empty

Comment: No, it's just a list of integers.

Comment: Nick is correct. values_list() returns a QuerySet, not a list.

Comment: It seems like it... I must have read the wrong documentation.

Comment: Forcing evaluation by using `list(self.profile.favorites...)` in the constructor made the problem go away.

Comment: Don't rely on documentation. Use the debugger. A set_trace in the right place would have given you both the change to step into and see what happened, and a type() would have told you it wasn't a list.

The debugger is a must-know tool.

Answer (score 0):

With *just* this snippet of code, it can't happen (assuming self.favorites and self.hello aren't properties).  My guess would be that something somewhere else is mutating the value of self.favorites or self.hello.  Is there another thread that could be doing this somewhere?  Or could this perhaps be happening in a different request?